# Windows Server 2003: Schedule FORFILE loop in TASK SCHEDULER

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting, scheduled-task

I am trying to create a SCHEDULED TASK that will kick off a FORFILE loop, and terminate the process after an hour (or 12 hours).  I expect there to be MILLIONS of files the the paths defined, and I want to run the task off-hours to minimize the performance impact.

The code I'm trying to run is:

forfiles /P "E:\Mutex_01" /S /M *.txt /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @path"

Looking in the logs, I don't get the sense that task is running correctly.  When I enumerate the folder, there is no change. Am I missing something? How can I become the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would do it differently... I would kick off the routine interactively and then schedule a script that has:

```
PSKILL forfiles.exe
PSKILL CMD.EXE
```

Schedule that script to run at a particular time with administrative credentials.

You could even do a test right now... start the forfiles routine, and schedule your kill script to run five minutes from now...

Comment: This worked!  Not allowed to use PSKill (even though it is a Sysinternals product), but was able to use it with TASKKILL.  Thanks!